# Generate a new sequence with values from a function

Tags: mapping, nim-lang

As per title, I have the following code:

```
proc squared(n: int64): int64 = n * n

echo squared(5)
```

which generates the following output:

```
25
```

However, if I know want a sequence populated using `squared`,  I would write something like:

```
import sequtils

proc squared_seq(n: int64): seq[int64] =
    result = newSeq[int64](n)
    for i in 0 ..< n:
        result[i] = squared(i)

echo squared_seq(5)
```

I would expect this produce the following output:

```
@[0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
```

But all I get is the following error (on the `result[i] = ...` line):

```
Error: type mismatch: got <seq[int64], int64, int64>
but expected one of: 
proc `[]=`(s: var string; i: BackwardsIndex; x: char)
proc `[]=`[T, U](s: var string; x: HSlice[T, U]; b: string)
proc `[]=`[T](s: var openArray[T]; i: BackwardsIndex; x: T)
proc `[]=`[Idx, T, U, V](a: var array[Idx, T]; x: HSlice[U, V]; b: openArray[T])
template `[]=`(s: string; i: int; val: char)
proc `[]=`[I: Ordinal; T, S](a: T; i: I; x: S)
proc `[]=`[T, U, V](s: var seq[T]; x: HSlice[U, V]; b: openArray[T])
proc `[]=`[Idx, T](a: var array[Idx, T]; i: BackwardsIndex; x: T)
```

Eventually, this is some form of mapping, therefore I had thought that this code could work:

```
var arr = toSeq(0 ..< 5)
var sq_arr = map(arr, squared)

echo sq_arr
```

with the same expected output as before:

```
@[0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
```

But I get instead (on the `map` line):

```
Error: type mismatch: got <seq[int], proc (n: int64): int64{.noSideEffect, gcsafe, locks: 0.}>
but expected one of: 
proc map[T](s: var openArray[T]; op: proc (x: var T) {.closure.})
first type mismatch at position: 2
required type: proc (x: var T){.closure.}
but expression 'squared' is of type: proc (n: int64): int64{.noSideEffect, gcsafe, locks: 0.}
proc map[T, S](s: openArray[T]; op: proc (x: T): S {.closure.}): seq[S]
first type mismatch at position: 2
required type: proc (x: T): S{.closure.}
but expression 'squared' is of type: proc (n: int64): int64{.noSideEffect, gcsafe, locks: 0.}
```

What am I doing wrong?

(I am on Nim 0.19.0, but it does not work on Nim 0.18.0 either).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Thanks to @leorize, @mratsim and @alehander42 from #nim in `freenode`).

The problem with the first solutions is that the index of a `seq` must be an `int` and the `int64` to `int` casting is not automatic.
Something like the following would work because the `int` to `int64` required by the signature of `squared` is automatic.

```
import sequtils

proc squared_seq(n: int64): seq[int64] =
    result = newSeq[int64](n)
    for i in 0 ..< int(n):
        result[i] = squared(i)
```

Alternatively, the following would also work:

```
proc squared_seq(n: int64): seq[int64] =
    result = newSeq[int64](n)
    for i in 0 ..< n:
        result[int(i)] = squared(i)
```

I am not quite sure however, why `result = newSeq[int64](n)` does not require `n` to be `int`, if later on only `int` indices are supported.
It seems to be an unwanted feature, though.

Regarding the *mapping* approach, the problem here is that the input type is `int`, while `squared()` requires `int64`. In this case, apparently the best way for that would be to use some way of proxy for the `int` to `int64` sequence, e.g.:

```
var arr = toSeq(0 ..< 5)
var sq_arr = map(arr, proc(x: int): int64 = squared(x))
```

or, better, force `toSeq` to produce `int64`, e.g.:

```
var arr = toSeq(0'i64 ..< 5'i64)
var sq_arr = map(arr, squared)
```

or even better, use a type-relaxed version of `map`, which is `mapIt`:

```
var arr = toSeq(0 ..< 5)
var sq_arr = mapIt(arr, squared(it))
```

which should also produce faster code.

Comment: When you write `newSeq[int64]` you are not specifying the type of the index to access the sequence but the type of data it contains. You could as well write `newSeq[float]` but would not expect to index with `result[0.5] = foo`, right?

Comment: I never meant that, but the fact that you have no control (but type-checks) over the index type seems a bit disappointing, especially since I would have expected a type-error to be thrown at the `newSeq[int64](n)` because of the unsupported type of `n` for `seq` indices.

Comment: I believe _sequences_ which allow you to specify the index type are usually called associative arrays or maps, and can be used in Nim through the `tables` module.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but it is not my point. My point is that in this specific case a type check is triggered too late in the code. In general, I see the point of having indices to be `int`, but had I had an overflow of `n`, `newSeq()` would have been silently ignoring this.

Comment: Too late? The compiler prevented you from compiling the source code and pointed you at the first usage of the incorrect index access potentially causing overflow. Granted the error message could have been more user friendly, but I can't see how `newSeq()` has anything to do with it.

Comment: `proc squared_seq(n: int64): seq[int64] = newSeq[int64](n)` would work but shouldn't because of the above arguments. I don't think I can explain this better than that.

Comment: Ah, indeed. You should file that as a bug, since `newSeq` is a _magic_ proc of the compiler and doesn't seem to be checking its parameters correctly. A 32bit install will happily run `newSeq` with a 64bit parameter and raise a RangeError at runtime, which shouldn't happen. OTOH if you write your own proc accepting `int`, you won't be able to pass it `int64'. Nice catch!

Answer (score 1):

The error happens because you are trying to use an `int64` to index the `result` sequence. Sequences are accessed using the generic `int` platform type, which [depending on your platform](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#types-preminusdefined-integer-types) might be 32bits long or 64bits. You can change the `squared_seq` parameter to `int` and it should compile:

```
import sequtils

proc squared(n: int64): int64 = n * n

proc squared_seq(n: int): seq[int64] =
    result = newSeq[int64](n)
    for i in 0 ..< n:
        result[i] = squared(i)

echo squared_seq(5)
```

Alternatively, you could cast the `int64` like `for i in 0 ..< int(n)`, but that could be dangerous depending on the values you pass to the proc.